# Cakephp plugin milesj forum

Tags: cakephp, plugins, forum

I'm getting following error when trying to install Admin
http://prntscr.com/282zhv

So, the Composer created folders Admin, Forum and Utility in app/Plugin folder.
In app\config\bootstrap.php file i have following lines

```
   CakePlugin::loadAll();
   CakePlugin::load('Utility', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
   CakePlugin::load('Admin', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
   CakePlugin::load('Forum', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
```

why Cake fails to find a plugin? :S

EDIT:
typing cake in app/console
http://prntscr.com/283lrq
typing cake while in app 
http://prntscr.com/283moc

Comment: what is the output of $cake? (Notice I wrote only "cake")

Comment: you should work from "app". I don't see any Shell with the name "Admin" in there, are you sure the Plugin is in there?

Comment: success! yeah, plugins were in app/plugin but also in mysite/plugins together with downloaded content. i removed that and now it works. (although i'm not sure why in milesJ instructions he is saying we should type that from app/console...) i still need to setup everything else but i hope i will manage. ty